# Stating the convergence radius of taylor series centred at $0$ of $\frac{1}{(1+z^2)(\cos 2z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I do this?

I tried considering the reciprocal: $g(z):= (1+z^2)\cos 2z$.

$g$ is entire, so $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1+z^2)(\cos 2z)}$ is analytic whenever the $g(z)\neq 0$.

I'm not sure what to do now. So $g$ has infinite radius of convergence, what does this say about $f$?

Also, $\cos 2z$ seems to have infinitely many zeroes, so I'm not sure what to do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least $|z|$ such that $\cos 2z=0$ is $\pi /4.$ The least $|z|$ for which $1+z^2=0$ is $1$, which is greater than $\pi /4.$ So $f(z)$ is analytic on $D=\{z:|z|<\pi /4\}.$

(1).If $f$ is analytic on $D$ then the power series for $f$ centered at $0$  will converge uniformly to $f$ on any $E\subset D$ such that $E$ is closed in $\Bbb C.$

(2). A power series converges uniformly on any compact (i.e. bounded, and closed in $\Bbb C$) subset of its open disc of convergence. And a uniform limit of a sequence of continuous complex  functions on a domain $G$ will be continuous on $G.$

So if the power series for $f$ centered at $0$ converged on some $F=\{z:|z|<R\}$ with $R>\pi/4$  then it would converge uniformly on $G=\{|z|: |z|\leq (R+\pi /4)/2\}$ to a continuous $g:G\to \Bbb C$ such that $g(z)=f(z)$ whenever $|z|<\pi /4.$  This would imply that $$g(\pi/4)=\lim_{x\to \pi /4; x\in (0,\pi /4)}g(x)=\lim_{x\to \pi /4; x\in (0,\pi/4)}f(x).$$ But the far RHS limit above does not exist. So the radius of convergence cannot exceed $\pi /4.$

Comment: (1). A deeper result is that if a sequence of analytic functions on an open domain $D$ converges uniformly to $ f $ on any compact $E\subset D$ then $f$ is analytic on $D$.... (2). A function may be analytic on $D$ and continuous on $\overline D$ but not extendable to an analytic function on any open set $D'\supset \overline D.$.... E.g. let $\log (z)$ be the principal branch of the complex logarithm  for $z\not \in (-\infty,0].$ Let $\bar D=\{|z|:|z|\leq 1\}.$ Let $f(-1)=0$ and $f(z)=(1+z)\log (1+z)$ for $0\ne z\in \bar D.$ The derivative $f'(z)$ mis-behaves at $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{(1+z^2)(\cos 2z)}$.

Let $S$ be the set of isolated singularities of $f$. It is your turn to determine the set $S$.

The radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is then given by

$$ \min \{|s|: s \in S\}.$$

Comment: Ah I see. So in this case it'd be $\pi/4$?

Comment: Yes, you are right !